# Bitmap not saving in application folder in android nougat

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gallery, android-7.0-nougat

i am working on bitmap save to application folder in android
below nougat its work fine but in nougat i have issue so can anyone help me?

below my code for save bitmap

```
    String getRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    File myDir = new File(getRoot + "/" + folderNAme);
    String fname = picName + format;
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(form, quality, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    act.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

    return file;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:-

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
   myDir.mkdirs();
   String fname = "filename.jpg";
   File file = new File (myDir, fname);
   if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
   try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: In app which i am working this app is not use camera its create image of view and i have to save in application folder in gallery

Comment: You mean to save the drawabeCache() of the View to external storage?

Comment: Could you try the above solution, I have used `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` instead of  `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to give runtime permissions for nougat for saving your file.

See this:
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html